# T-SQL. What is the best approach to implement "any" where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine you have a table of orders with statuses:

```
Id (PK)
Status (INT) 
...
```

There is user interface (UI) where business user may select what status for orders he is interested in. There is a magic number "-1" that means - user is interested in every status

What is the best way and considerations how to implement the query:

```
1. select * from orders where status = @user-selected-status-id or @user-selected-status-id = -1

2. select * from orders where status = ISNULL(NULLIF(@user-selected-status-id, -1), status) 

3. Dynamic sql approach with string concatenation "where" operator is joined only if required (EXEC sp_executesql at the very end)
```

I used "Execution plan" for all three approaches and it tells that estimated cost is the very best for dynamic sql, then isnull/nullif and "or" is outsider.

I used to think that "or" approach should outperform because of it's brievity isnull/nullif approach

What amused me even more - that results (estimations) depend on size of order table. When it's grew ten times (from 10K -> 100K rows) outsider was "dynamic sql".

May I trust this?

Comment: We have used a stored procedure in cases like this and had an IF statement with one query with the where clause and one without.

Comment: Thank you, @SteveB, but your approach wouldn't work good is there would be several parameters like 'status'. Too many if/else clauses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gail Shaw did a couple of great articles on this: [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [Revisting Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/).

The summary of these, however, is that is you are on 2008- then go with **parametrised** dynamic statements. If you are on SQL Server 2012+ then go with the `WHERE Column = @Variable OR @Variable IS NULL` and add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end.

If, however, you do have an expensive query in terms of generating the query plan, then you might want to still use dynamic SQL. Then, each of the statements will have their own cached plan, provided they are called often enough.

What ever though, don't go with `status = ISNULL(NULLIF(@user-selected-status-id, -1), status)`. That clause is non-SARGable and will have the worst perfomance of the bunch.

So, the 2012+ method (for a non high complexity query plan in terms of generation) would be:

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE (YT.Column = @Variable
   OR  @Variable IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

`OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is important, as it causes the data engine to recreate the query plan (and estimates) each time the query is run. If you have a query where `@Variable` has a value, then the number of rows that is going to be returned is going to be estimated as "low" (respectively). On the other hand, for a query where the value of `@Variable` is `NULL` then that means that **every** row is going to be returned (in this simple query); or a "high" number of rows. SQL Server caches plans, which means that a plan for when there is a low number would not be good for when there is a high number. Bad estimates can (and do) mean poor performance as things can overspill from RAM in tempdb, and resource time isn't what was expected. Forcing the data engine to recreate the plan means those estimates will be recreated for each run (which does come at a cost), but will be far better for the query being run; provided your statistics are up to date too.

If, however, you're on SQL Server 2008, you don't have access to `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, so you'll need to go down the dynamic route:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT {Columns}' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM YourTable' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           CASE WHEN @Variable IS NOT NULL THEN N'WHERE YT.Column = @Variable' ELSE '' END + N';';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Variable {DataType}', @Variable = @Variable;
```

Comment: I'd recommend to read the [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog. The article by Gail Shaw that you reference mentions Erland Sommarskog, but points to an older version. The main point is that SQL Server 2008 (after SP2) has `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` working properly.

Comment: @Larnu, thank you for the articles you've provided but I still wonder why execution plan chooses different winners depending on size of the table :(

Comment: Aaron Bertrand also [wrote about this problem](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) - His recommendation is to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @user149691 This actually might not be related to the parameter sniffing problem - The query optimizer choose what indexes to use based on the coverage and the size of the data. When the table is small, using an index is not that effective as using the same index when the table is large - and sometimes might even provide worst results than a simple table scan.